# Why Unity3D 2018 UI looks bad and very sharpy?

Tags: unity, sprites, gui, text

I update my project from Unity 2017.1.1 to 2018.3.9 and almost everything is OK except UIs.
All of UIs like Images,Buttons,texts,text mesh pro, sprites and others looks very sharpy and pixel pixel ...

please see the attached image :

Unity3D 2017 before update :

[image]

Unity3D 2018 after update :

[image]

why this happens ? and how can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Can you double-check your desktop scaling / high-DPI display settings? I observe something similar on my Surface in Windows, because by default Windows asks the app to draw at 2/3rds resolution, then upscales the result 150%. Disabling this lets it render at native resolution without the upscaling pass

Comment: YES !!! IT WORKs !!!  Thank you @DMGregory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We just need to change Scale and layout to 100% in windows setting panel .

[image]

And in advanced scaling setting I turn on "Let Windows try to fix apps so they're not blurry" .

After that Unity UI problem is gone.